Question about immersed manifolds with boundary
I am currently studying chapters 4 and 5 of Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds and I have a question about the definition about immersions with boundary. Since we can give an immersed manifold any topology we please, we can consider the unit square in the plane as a union of two closed intervals and two open intervals. However, these are embeddings of the manifold $(-1,1)$ and $[-1,1]$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$. So we get a map from $[-1,1] \sqcup [-1,1] \sqcup (-1,1) \sqcup (-1,-1)$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the differential is injective so that the map is an immersion. But I know that the unit square is not an immersion, so what is going on?

Your confusion probably stems from conflating of maps and sets: Immersion is a map, square is a set. My suggestion is to avoid the language of immersed submanifolds and work only with immersions.
